# Skip import row, is not valid value “” for field “type”

Tags: magento-1.9

i am using .xml file to import product in my new magento setup without sample data.. but after import, it gives an error...

Found 7 rows.

```
Starting catalog/convert_adapter_product :: parse
Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"
Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"
Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"
Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"
Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"
Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"
Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"
Processed 100% 7/7 records
Imported 0 records
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an exported CSV file to import in Magento then you need to make some changes to column titles.

> Skip import row, is not valid value "" for field "type"

The error occurs when you either have not defined a column with name `type` in your CSV file or you are not adding any value to that column.

It also happens if you have an `_` before column name like `_type`

Change the column title from `_type` to `type` and it should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're not specifying a valid product type in your import file. You should check spelling and any extra spaces. The only valid types are "simple" "bundled" "grouped" "configurable" "virtual" and "download." These should all be lowercase, as well.

It might help to paste in one of the rows that is being rejected so we can see exactly what is there.

Comment: im facing the same issue...I have tried out 'simple' without any spaces, my column name is _type...Whats the solution?